# IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

My code was working fine until I updated Numpy to 1.13.1. Now I get the  following error

```
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 5 but corresponding boolean dimension is 4
```

... which is thrown at this line:

```
m = arr[np.diff(np.cumsum(arr) >= sum(arr) * i)]
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around it. Any suggestions?

Here is my sample code:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
l = [0.85,0.90]
s = sorted(a, reverse = False)
arr = np.array(s)
for i in l:
    m = arr[np.diff(np.cumsum(arr) >= sum(arr) * i)]
```

Comment: Add sample case that reproduces that issue?

Comment: type remains same as input: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`np.diff` is one element smaller than data_array.

> The shape of the output is the same as a except along axis where the
>   dimension is smaller by n.

[numpy.diff](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)

I am using Numpy 1.11,  instead of an `IndexError` I get a `VisibleDeprecationWarning`. So I guess using an incorrect size is no longer tolerated.

You need to define which behaviour you want, e.g. start at the second element, or remove the last:

```
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

arr2 = arr[:-1]
m = arr2[np.diff(np.cumsum(arr) >= sum(arr))]

arr3 = arr[1:]
m = arr3[np.diff(np.cumsum(arr) >= sum(arr))]
```

Comment: Thanks. Instead I appended '0' to original array keep all data points.